# FirebaseUI Auth Doesn't Work for Google and Facebook

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I've been using FirebaseUI Auth and it's suddenly stopped working for Google and Facebook Sign-in. I haven't changed anything—all the cocoapods are the same. It was working yesterday. What's going on?

Here's the error that I get:

```
FValidation.m line 60
+[FValidation validateFrom:validRootPathString:]
Fatal Exception: InvalidPathValidation
(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']'
```

Sometimes the error says this instead:

```
+[FValidation validateFrom:validPathString:]:
```

It occurs after pressing "OK" on the Facebook sign-in and after pressing "Allow" on the Google sign in. The error occurs before the `didSignInWithUser:` method on the `authViewController` can fire. Both Facebook and Google authentication are enabled in the Firebase dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I deleted everything in the `NSDocuments` folder in `applicationWillResignActive`. I was hoping just to delete images, but I ended up also deleting: "com.google.iid-keypair.plist",  "g-checkin.plist, and "rmq2.sqlite"

This was an issue because when using Facebook or Google authentication, `applicationWillResignActive` is called. I fixed it by deleting `NSDocuments` files selectively and by doing it in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` method.